# How can I open the messages app on mobile when using React JS?

Tags: reactjs, mobile, sms

I am trying to get functionality where my website opens up the message app on mobile, However after searching online, I can only find a solution for react native. Is this feature supported for react JS? And if so, how would I implement this?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find a solution. Just add a href of 'sms:/*phonenumber*'